# How to design my database with 2 possible FK in NHibernate

Tags: sql-server, database, nhibernate

I am trying to create game where I use a restful server to control multiplayer games

The game is a board game with 2 players, but I am in doubt how to create my database so it makes sense

One player will have a foreign key to a gameID but another player will as well (Player 1 and Player 2)

So if my game model has something like

```
public virtual GameId {get;set;}
......
public virtual Player1Id {get;set;}
public virtual Player2Id {get;set;}
```

Then how am I supposed to create the database when a PlayerId can be both at the Player1 and Player2 spot in the game model? The FK cant link to a certain spot everytime and thats my worry

Ps I my database experience is rather limited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't need a PlayerId on your game object. The player object needs a GameId to reference it.

This creates a one-to-many relationship.  Each game has many players.  Although in reality in your situation you are describing only having two players for one game.

The other alternative would be to have PlayerOneId and PlayerTwoId as foreign keys, therefore creating two one-to-one relationships.

Comment: Ok, one - many is probobly better as I can then reuse that later if I get more gametypes with more players in one game

Comment: But will cause problems if one player can be playing multiple games at once. I think the logic would imply that the games are transitory, but the players are persistent, in which case your Player1Id and Player2Id make more sense. Or, if you envision variable player-counts, have a join table, with GameId and PlayerID - basically many-to-many.

Comment: If you are going to potentially have other game types with varying numbers of players then a many-to-many (with a join table obviously) is probably best as mentioned above since it does give you better flexibility. You certainly shouldn't just keeping adding multiple player columns to the game if that is the case.